# in sql,How does fixed-length data type take place in memory?

Tags: sql

I want to know in sql,how fixed-length data type take places length in memory?I know is that for varchar,if we specify length is (20),and if user input length is 15,it takes 20 by setting space.for varchar2,if we specify length is (20),and if user input is 15,it only take 15 length in memory.So how about fixed-length data type take place?I searched in Google,but I did not find explanation with  example.Please explain me with example.Thanks in advance.

Comment: That'll **highly** depend on the actual, concrete DBMS you're using - please tag your question with `sql-server`, `oracle`, `mysql`, `postgresql` or whatever else you might be using

Answer (score 0):

A fixed length data field always consumes its full size.

In the old days (FORTRAN), it was padded at the end with space characters.  Modern databases might do that too, but either implicitly trim trailing blanks off or the query might have to do it explicitly.

Variable length fields are a relative newcomer to databases, probably in the 1970s or 1980s they made widespread appearances.

It is considerably easier to manage fixed length record offsets and sizes rather than compute the offset of each data item in a record which has variable length fields.  Furthermore, a fixed length data record is easily addressed in a data file by computing the byte offset of its beginning by multiplying the record size times the record number (and adding the length of whatever fixed header data is at the beginning of file).

Comment: so a fixed length data field always consumes its full size means is that if we define length as 20,but user input is 5,then it occupy 20 by setting space just like varchar take place in memory?

Comment: @sawyinwaimon:  All of that is true, except I don't understand what you mean about varchar.   `varchar` has to remember the length of the data in addition to the data, so it is a little more complicated.

Comment: How data is stored is product specific, there's no general answer.